# logger.setLevel is not a function while running logger.js using log4js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, logging, log4js-node

I am trying to create logs files using log4js. While running node app.js after doing all the configurations i am getting the below error.

**Error:**

```
TypeError: logger.setLevel is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Angular\logging_project\routes\logger.js:14:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Angular\logging_project\routes\index.js:3:13)
```

Please look at my code.

**logger.js**

```
  var log4js = require('log4js');
  log4js.configure({
     appenders: {
        console: { type: 'console' },
        filelog: { type: 'file', filename: "c://test.log", category: 'my_project' }
      },
      categories: {
         file: { appenders:['filelog'],level:'error'},
         another: {appenders: ['console'],level: 'trace'},
         default: {appenders: ['console','filelog'],level: 'trace'}
      }
   });
  var logger  = log4js.getLogger('my_project');
        logger.setLevel('DEBUG');
        Object.defineProperty(exports, "LOG", {
                    value:logger,
 })
```

**index.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var logger= require('./logger.js');
var log=logger.LOG;
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

exports.index = function(req, res){
log.debug("testing the debug log here....................");
log.error("testing the error log here....................");
log.info("testing the info log here....................");
log.trace("testing the trace log here....................");
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var log = require('./routes/logger');
var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

//use logger
app.use(log4js.connectLogger(log, { level: log4js.levels.DEBUG }));

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
console.log('node Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});

module.exports = app;
```

I am new to node js and this is the first time i am creating log files using node js. Anybody please help me in resolving the issue. It could be better if i get a working code. I am stuck with this for the whole day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the logger level using following code:

```
logger.level = 'DEBUG';
```

Comment: thank you. It worked for me. My node app.js is running without errors. It is creating a log file with name 'test'. But the log file is empty. there is no logs found that i have added.  Is there any other mistake i am doing in my code?

Comment: I was able to see the logs in the test.log file. If you are using Windows, try to update the code in logger.js Line 5:
`filelog: { type: 'file', filename: "./test.log", category: 'my_project' }`